# How to use Domain_builder module?

Tags: frama-c

I would like to implement a simple abstract domain using functors provided by module  Domain_builder (documented in section EVA->Domains), but I am not able to open the module. A simple ocaml file x.ml:

```
open Domain_builder
```

and command `frama-c -load-script x.ml` produce error *Unbound module Domain_builder*. I am, however, able to import other modules documented in this section (e.g. Cvalue).

It seems that module Domain_builder is not exported by EVA's .mli file (https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/blob/master/src/plugins/value/Eva.mli), but neither is Cvalue module.

Am I doing something wrong, or is Domain_builder module really missing in EVA's signature?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you're right, `Domain_builder` cannot be used outside of Eva for now
(NB: if it was exported, you'd have to `open Eva.Domain_builder` in any case).

As for why `Cvalue` is available: for historical reasons, this module, together with all files within `src/plugins/value_types` are in fact considered as kernel modules.